# Send NDEF message from Android device using Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nfc, xamarin

I want to send an NDEF message from one Android device to other device. Not to write in a tag, but send the message to the nearby device.

I'm using Xamarin.Android to develop the Android app and I create the message like this:

```cs
    NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.CreateUri("http://myURL");
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new[] { uriRecord });
```

I now want to send the message when nearby device is detected, but I don't know how it is done. Xamarin's documentation is not complete, and I'm not familiar with Android development.

Could anyone help me or show a simple example?

Comment: Read the Android documentation. It applies in most cases almost directly to Xamarin.Android. Minor changes such as Listeners are often Events in Xamarin.Android and some methods are replaced by Properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out.

1. The main activity has to implement `NfcAdapter.ICreateNdefMessageCallback` and `NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback` interfaces.
2. Implement `CreateNdefMessage` and `OnNdefPushComplete` methods.
3. Call `SetNdefPushMessageCallback` and `SetOnNdefPushCompleteCallback` methods of `NfcAdapter` in the `OnCreate` method of the main activity.

```cs
public class Activity1 : Activity, NfcAdapter.ICreateNdefMessageCallback, NfcAdapter.IOnNdefPushCompleteCallback
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        ...

        NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.GetDefaultAdapter(this);
        adapter.SetNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
        adapter.SetOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);           
    }

    public NdefMessage CreateNdefMessage(NfcEvent e)
    {
        NdefRecord uriRecord = NdefRecord.CreateUri("http://myURL");
        NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new[] { uriRecord });
        return message;
    }

    public void OnNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was this difficult to implement.  I'm looking at doing the same thing.  Sending a message to another android device on NFC without cell signal.